# unable to import basically anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I cant import anything I have tried everything; using pip in cmd, importing in python(of course) and done every pip command, it always says done and complete. but then in python and pycharm I cant import it. the cmd also says after i download an importation ( ;) ) that I am running an older version of pip; does this have to do with anything? please answer. I am also very new to python so excuse me if I said anything strange or completely wrong.

-Joep

Comment: Maybe the Python `--version` you run pip with is another than that you run in pycharm.

Comment: The `path` variable may be incorrectly set. In the python installer did you make sure to allow it to add to path?

Comment: Pycharm is able to configure the python interpreter per project. You should go to settings to see which one is set. When you pick the right one you will be able to see all the installed packages. (I much prefer to install new packages from within Pycharm)

Comment: You probably have several versions of Python installed and calling `pip` could call a pip not matching the python interpreter called with `python` or registered with PyCharm,. Instead of `pip`, try `python -m pip`, then you are sure to use pip belonging to your default python installation. You may also want to check Setttings - >Project -> Python interpreter in PyCharm. It shows the interpreter version and all installed modules for all python interpreters known to PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

**Uninstall** Python and **Install** it again but select the  **"Add To The PATH"** option to make `pip` and `python example.py` commands or other commands Installed to the System PATH

PyCharm recognizes it automatically when it's installed in the System Path.

I Hope Its Works :)

~Derin O. Eren